# В чем заключается разыменование массива?

Tags: php

```
function countBasket($arr) {
    $sum = 0;
    forEach ($arr as ["quan" => $quan]) {
        $sum += $quan;
    }
    echo $sum;
    return $sum;
}

$basket = [
    ['pos' => 'Книга по php', 'quan' => 1,],
    ['pos' => 'Мышь компьютерная', 'quan' => 2,],
    ['pos' => 'Ручка шариковая', 'quan' => 5,]
];

countBasket($basket);
```

Comment: вроде бы код прекрасно показывает, что происходит. в чем вопрос?

Comment: Задача заключается, цитирую: Нельзя применять разыменовывание массивов:

foreach ($arr as [...])

Используйте классический вариант написания цикла foreach

Comment: Когда я переношу тело в стороннюю консоль, там выдает ошибку "Нельзя применять разыменовывание массивов"

Comment: `forEach ($arr as $x) {  $sum += $x["quan"];`

Comment: Афигеть. Есть прогресс, спасибо! Но все же, есть возможность прояснить этот термин "разыменование"?? Буду благодарна!

Comment: в данном случае, из каждого элемента массива просто берется только один ключ. собственно, неявно выполняется то, что я вам написал в цикле. если вместо $x подставить $quan, Будет еще ближе

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.